# annotate function in R adding symbols to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols, annotate

I want to annotate a plot where I will be displaying the maximum and minimum values for some plots. When I run the annotate statements individually they print the symbol on the plot correctly. But when I run it in a for loop and generate many plots for many values the symbols are turned into "???".

Please clarify what is the issue.

> plot = plot + annotate("text", x = 35, y = 925, label = paste("↑","Max 2009/10",sep=""))

The plot is a part of the function the function loops on its arguments. So the plots getting generated are saved as png in a particular folder. The function and the call are in two different R Scripts

> lapply(FUN = get_weather_details,X = list)

Comment: Your code works fine both within and outside a for loop when I try it on my system (using the `mtcars` data frame just to have some data to plot). Could you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can see exactly what data you're plotting and what your loop code looks like?

Comment: Sounds like the character encoding isn't set correctly.

Comment: I have added further details to the question.

Answer (score -1):

When you are running it individually you get the correct symbol, but in loop you get ???. I tried using pch for symbols and I am able to annotate it.